# Burninate [roblox-studio] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I created the [roblox-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox-studio) tag with the hope that it would be a place for developers to discuss issues with and solutions for plugins and extensions of the [Roblox Studio IDE](https://www.roblox.com/create). I worded the usage guidelines after the [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) tag, hoping that people would realize that it was specifically for questions related *to* the IDE and not for code that was written *in* the IDE.

However, it appears that most new questions appearing in the [roblox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox) tag are coming with the automatic suggestion of adding [roblox-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox-studio) as well. Since [roblox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox) is commonly a space for beginners as well as new SO members, I feel that [roblox-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox-studio) is not useful nor has it become meaningfully distinct from [roblox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox), and worse it is distracting beginners from providing actually meaningful information in their titles, questions, and tags.

I would like to request that this tag be burninated.

Out of [the 4 listed criterion for burnination requests](/a/324071), it only fails number 3: it does not add any meaningful information to a question. Out of the roughly 30 tagged questions, only one is correctly using the tag, and all the others are using it incorrectly or as a synonym for [roblox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox). However, I would argue that it is doing harm, as the pool of people that regularly respond to [roblox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox) questions is already fairly small, and [roblox-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox-studio) segments that pool and creates confusion about where to actually get help for questions.

Comment: [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](/a/324071/11107541) please see the criterion for burnination proposals.

Comment: It's a common problem across the site for users tagging their editor when they actually have a problem with the code they've written inside the editor. It's a subtype of users adding any tags they can think of for all technologies used even though the tags are irrelevant to the question. So, [[tag:roblox-studio]] it's not unique here. Not to say it doesn't deserve attention but I think burnination is too harsh. There are currently 28 questions. Probably not hard to keep an eye on the tag and remove wrong usages to keep it clean.

Comment: While it is not difficult to monitor the tag and edit questions as they come in, it is still effort. I have removed the tag from easily 2 dozen questions already, and the 27 that are left are because I have let them get out of hand. So I am partly asking for selfish reasons, but if only 1 out of 50 questions are using the tag correctly, at what point can I ask that the tag be removed just so that I don't have to keep making the same edits over and over again?

Comment: For tags with less than 50 questions, you don't need a formal burnination process. Removing the tag of all questions that use it will make the tag eligible for automatic deletion (it's around midnight UTC every day). So you could do it yourself, if you feel the need. The tag can still be recreated in the future but only by a user with [the create tag privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) adding it to a question.

Comment: @VLAZ, that sounds like a good path forward in my opinion. If you want to write that as an answer I'll accept it, unless an alternative is proposed.

Comment: @VLAZ "It's a common problem across the site for users tagging their editor when they actually have a problem with the code they've written inside the editor." This is just one of many reasons why we ought never have accepted questions about the editor as on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an update, I have followed @VLAZ's advice and simply removed the tag from every question.
As such, the tag has been deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't fail **all four** burnination criteria, then it doesn't qualify for burnination:

> A tag must fail ALL of those tests in order to be considered for burnination.

I'd also question whether your description of it failing #3 is accurate. Just because you don't see a question about the Roblox Studio IDE yet doesn't mean one won't ever need to exist. Now when someone has a question about Roblox Studio itself and not Roblox code in general, they'll need to recreate the tag.

Presumably the question you first tagged with [roblox-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox-studio) was about the IDE itself. What happened to that question? After a quick search I've already found multiple questions that are directly about the IDE itself or critically related to the IDE, so I've gone ahead and recreated that tag to help users search for it.